# Why does this output 8?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String... args) {

        int i=010;

        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

output:

```
8
```

Why? What is the logic?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`0` is the prefix for octal numbers, just like `0x` is the prefix for hexadecimal numbers (and `0b` is the prefix for binary numbers, since Java 7).

So `010` means `1 * 81 + 0 * 80`, which is `8`.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal may be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal
>   (base 16), **octal (base 8)**, or binary (base 2).
>
> An **octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7** interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

This is why `010` = `8`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `010`, here  is octal  .

Answer (score 2):

The integer is in octal-System because you have 0 at start.

Answer (score 0):

Using **0 prefix** means that you are using **octal** numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Java and several other languages, an integer literal beginning with `0` is interpreted as an octal (base 8) quantity.

If you write numbers with more than one significant digit you might be confused by the result.

```
// octal to decimal
01  == 1
02  == 2
07  == 7
010 == 8
020 == 16
024 == 20

// octal to binary (excluding most significant bit)
01  == 1 
02  == 10
07  == 111
010 == 1000 
020 == 10000
024 == 10100
```